# onchange = "myForm.submit() only working for the first subdropdown in my dropdown menu

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a dropdown list with the names of 5 teams, and then a sub dropdown that contains the names of the people in each team.
I am trying to make the form work so that when you click on someone's name, you can see their stats.

The first team in the dropdown works perfectly. The other four don’t. This persists no matter which team is currently occupying the top slot.
If I select a team member from a non-working team, the page still refreshes but the data does not change.

Using chrome developer tools I can see that if I select a team member from the top team the option in the HTML becomes option selected. If I select a team member from any other team this does not occur.
But, if I put another function on the non-working-teams that displays the name of a selected person, and then select a team member from the non-working teams, that works!

I have seen similar problems when different `div`s had the same ID. These `div`s do not have the same ID but they do all have the same name (which is generated automatically by the class I am passing the userID into)
What do you guys think?

The HTML for my first two teams:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="yourteam">
            <h3>Teams</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <div class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">Team1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <div id='Team1' class="dropdown-menu">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.User, new SelectList(Model.1Members, "Value", "Key"), "Team Members", new { @class = "namedrop", @id = "Name1", onchange = "myForm.submit()" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">Team2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <div id='Team2' class="dropdown-menu">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.User, new SelectList(Model.2Members, "Value", "Key"), "Team Members", new { @class = "namedrop", @id = "Name2", @onchange = "myForm.submit()" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- The rest of the teams -->
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Since the form has multiple elements that have the same name it will most likely be interpreted on the server side as an array of values. Check that the server is properly handling the data that is posted

Comment: Would it be easier just to change the names of the different elements? or would that not work because I used HTML.DropdownListFor?

Comment: You're using DDLF binding to same property, why not combine them both into a single `SelectList` and use multiple selections? I think you can't have 2 DDLF with same name on the same form.

Comment: What would the syntax for that look like? Sorry I am very new to this.

Comment: Try using `ListBoxFor` (LBF) instead of `DropDownListFor` (DDLF) if you want multiple selections. However, if you want binding from multiple dropdowns, you should use `for` loop and bound to list/array of values.

Answer (score 0):

```
 onchange = "myForm.submit()"
```

you missed @ before onchange